# How to write a test in cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

This is my first test case with cucumber and I am having tough time to figure out one thing. So I already have a test which check user creation. I want to add more steps like on user create create account and create product and set some attributes to these objects.

Here is the user create feature file

```
@no-database-cleaner

Feature: Creating an user account
  In order to use Recdns portal
  I need to create an user account

  Scenario:  Successful user account creation
    Given the database contains no test data
    And I am on the homepage
    When I attempt to create the following user account:
      | email address        | password | confirm password |
      | abc@company1.com  | password | password         |
  # User is automatically logged in
    Then I should see "Welcome!" message on page
    And an ar_id is set for the user
    And
    When I click "Sign Out"
    Then I should see "Signed out"
    When I attempt to sign in with following user account:
      | email address         | password |
      | abc@company1.com   | password |
    Then I should see "Welcome!" message on page

  Scenario Outline:  Verify error message when user failed to sign in
    Given there is a user
    And I am on the homepage
    And I try to login with email "<email address>", password "<password>"
    Then I should see "<error message>" message on page

  Examples:
    | email address                        | password          | error message                        |
    | testuser@company1.com                | abc1234           | Invalid email or password            |
    | testuserdoesnotexist@company1.com    | password          | Invalid email or password            |

  Scenario Outline:  Verify error message when user failed to sign up
    Given I am on the homepage
    And I click "Sign Up"
    And I try to create user with email "<email address>", password "<password>", confirm password "<confirm password>"
    Then I should see "<error message>" message on page

  Examples:
    | email address       | password          | confirm password      | error message                        |
    | abc@company1.com | abc123            | abc123                | Email has already been taken         |
    | xyz@test         | abc123            | abc123                | Email is invalid                     |
    |                     | abc123            | abc123                | Email can't be blank                 |
    | abc@company1.com |                   | abc123                | Password can't be blank              |
    | abc@company1.com | abc123            |                       | Password doesn't match confirmation  |
    | abc@company1.com | abc1              | abc1                  | Password is too short                |
```

So where exactly I can add steps saying create account table and product table. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking where to put additional scenarios?  Or where the step definitions are located?  If it's additional scenarios, you can add to the current `.feature` file or create new `.feature` files with the new scenarios.  Just remember to keep the scenarios independent so that you're not depending on state from previous scenarios, which will eventually lead to brittle tests.

Answer (score 0):

Is your 'create user account' method something that you need for each test to run? If so, I'd just create a helper that you can call before your scenario. ..something like @needs_new_account.  One of the best parts about cucumber is the ability to reuse environments.  You probably shouldn't create a new account for each scenario. Instead, have cucumber remember that it needs to keep that new account (ie., dont delete it) and reuse for the rest of your scenarios, if possible. Let me know if this helps. ..not quite sure I'm understanding your question completely.

Also, you don't need your extra "and" between "and" and "when"...Gherkin syntax treats And/When/Then the same.

Comment: How you do that? reusing environment? I have few test that I will be using on user. But right now my test code create user every time I run test.

Comment: I put this in my env.rb file and create a new Before block for each matching helper.  For example, say you have a helper called @needs_login for a feature that hits the user's profile page (and clearly needs to be logged in to see the profile page).  In this feature, you don't need to check that the login works more than once since you're going to be doing the same login steps for each scenario.  So, instead you can reference your needs login in front of your feature and write a Before "method" helper in your env file that makes the test skip deleting cookies for each scenario.

Comment: I have a blog that mainly focuses on mobile, but this seems like a great topic for the site.  I'll post an example on my blog within the next couple of days that you can reuse (since I cant do it in less than 500 characters on here--lol)

Comment: Thanks. I having one more issue in my test. My code on sign up create bunch on record like account, user_selected_category, filter. So when I run my test everything get created sucessfully except user_selected_category. user_selected_category is join table. My code in dev env runs fine but fails to create user_selected_category in test. This is my very first test case and I have no idea how i can debug this. Any sugesstions? Thanks for the above tip.

Comment: Awesome!  All of it, or just the one that you needed help debugging (not the environment)

Comment: Everything. Thanks for help.